# Clojure - idiomatic way to write split-first and split-last

Tags: clojure, split

What would be the idiomatic way of writing the following function ?

```
(split-first #"." "abc.def.ghi") ;;=>["abc", "def.ghi"]
(split-last #"." "abc.def.ghi") ;;=>["abc.def", "ghi"]
```

There is an obvious (ugly ?) solution using `split`, but I'm sure there are more elegant solutions ? Maybe using regexes/indexOf/split-with ?

Comment: split first is just `(clojure.string/split "abc.def.ghi" #"\." 2)`

Comment: @cfrick That's very elegant. Should you have something for `split-last` equally good, I'd gladly accept your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For split-first, the best approach would be:

```
(defn split-first [re s]
  (clojure.string/split s re 2))

(split-first #"\." "abc.def.ghi") 
=> ["abc" "def.ghi"]

(split-first #"<>" "abc<>def<>ghi")
=> ["abc" "def<>ghi"]
```

One approach for split-last is to use a negative lookahead assertion:

```
(defn split-last [re s]
  (let [pattern (re-pattern (str re "(?!.*" re ")"))]
    (split-first pattern s)))

(split-last #"\." "abc.def.ghi")
=> ["abc.def" "ghi"]

(split-last #"<>" "abc<>def<>ghi")
=> ["abc<>def" "ghi"]
```

Comment: Nice idea, but you'll have to `reverse` regexp as well. Right now your solution will only work for palindrome patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I switched to a solution using a negative lookahead assertion

Answer (score 1):

If you do not necessarily need regexp matching this would work:

```
(defn index-of
  [^String s c]
  (.indexOf s c))

(defn last-index-of
  [^String s c]
  (.lastIndexOf s c))

(defn split-at-index-fn
  [f c s]
  (let [i (f s c)]
    ; I do not know what you want returned if no match is found
    (when-not (neg? i)
      [(.substring s 0 i) (.substring s (inc i))])))

(def split-first
  (partial split-at-index-fn index-of))

(def split-last
  (partial split-at-index-fn last-index-of))
```

This is not quite idiomatic, because it is mostly just Java interop.

Comment: you can save a few chars and if you don't like the looks of the interop by using `subs` instead of `.substring`, but meh

Comment: when no match is found, it should return an empty vector (I think that's the most logical thing to do, feel free to disagree)

Comment: @nha, okay, that is pretty easy to implement by changing `when-not` to `if-not` and returning an empty vector in the else-block.

Comment: @ponzao right. But I'd like it to work with a regex if possible ?

Comment: Then this implementation unfortunately will not fit your bill, @toolkit's solution should I think.

Comment: Thanks anyway, it might be useful to someone else. +1 :)